Changing the text color for the SSH terminal prompt in Debian Bookworm
I just installed Debian Bookworm on a Raspberry Pi 4B.  I work 90+% of the time via an SSH session.  In this mode the screen in a sea of white characters on a black background.  This makes finding the last command more difficult than I think it should be.  To that end I researched how to change the colors of the prompt, the $PS1 variable in the ~/.bashrc script.
I created a new PS1 like this PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;33m\]\u@\h:\[\033[0;34m\]\w\[\033[0m\]$ ' which has the host and user in yellow (interestingly lite brown) and the directory in blue.  This works in the ~/.bashrc file when I save it and then run source ~/.bashrc.  BUT, when I reboot it reverts to the default: white on black.
What am I doing wrong?...RDK45

I do this in /etc/profile.d/redrootprompt.sh
if [ "$LOGNAME" = root ] || [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ] ; then

    PS1='[\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\w] : '

else
    PS1='[\u@\h \w] : '
fi

simply having some .sh file under /etc/profile.d/ file, with -rw-r--r-- permissions, will be run (sourced) whenever you login or open a terminal.  I keep default white for everything other than root hence the if statement.  If you don't care about that then just remove the if statement and use the first PS1 statement.  Or modify the context of the if statement accordingly to control which accounts or uid's get color change.
for different colors than red [31m] see
What color codes can I use in my Bash PS1 prompt?
realize if you set color, you also have to unset it... as in set it back to white.
And if you use csh or tcsh then here is that syntax for an /etc/profile.d/something.csh file:
# /etc/profile.d/coloreduserprompt.csh

set     red="%{\033[1;31m%}"
set   green="%{\033[0;32m%}"
set  yellow="%{\033[1;33m%}"
set    blue="%{\033[1;34m%}"
set magenta="%{\033[1;35m%}"
set    cyan="%{\033[1;36m%}"
set   white="%{\033[0;37m%}"
set     end="%{\033[0m%}"


set prompt="${cyan}%n:${white}%~ ${cyan}:${end} "


Great.  I'll try this later today.  I thought that the ~/.bashrc was always run at startup?  OH well, I like your solution, if I'm successful later today I'll make it the answer.
